# Check whether value entered in text box falls between values of two other text boxes

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net

I have three textboxes. If the value entered in textbox 3 (numeric) is between the values of textbox 1 (numeric) and textbox 2 (numeric), or between the values of textbox 2 and textbox 1 then the result is okay, else it is not okay.

How can this be done with VB.NET?

Answer (score 2):

I haven't written any VB for years, but i think the formula you are looking for can be expressed as:

```
Return (z >= x And z <= y) Or (z >= y And z <= x)
```

Where:

- x is the value from textbox 1
- y is the value from textbox 2
- z is the value from textbox 3

Here is my (rusty) attempt at the VB to handle this:

```
Function IsOk(ByVal firstValue As String, ByVal secondValue As String, ByVal thirdValue As String) As String
    If firstValue.IsInteger() And secondValue.IsInteger() And thirdValue.IsInteger() Then
        Dim x As Integer = Integer.Parse(firstValue)
        Dim y As Integer = Integer.Parse(secondValue)
        Dim z As Integer = Integer.Parse(thirdValue)

        If (z >= x And z <= y) Or (z >= y And z <= x) Then
           Return "OK"
        End If
    End If
    
    Return "Not OK"
End Function

Public Module MyExtensions

    <System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Extension()> _
    Public Function IsInteger(ByVal value As String) As Boolean
        If String.IsNullOrEmpty(value) Then
            Return False
        Else
            Return Integer.TryParse(value, Nothing)
        End If
    End Function

End Module
```

Comment: I appreciate your prompt response. Swaton, I tried the above, but we didn't get the expected result. When x = 125, y = 75, and z = 100, for example. Because z is between x and y, this condition should yield the result "OK."

Comment: @Coder_Techie: The logic in the above looks good, I tried it out with slightly modified input methods and it returns True for x=125, y=75, z=100. You must be calling it in a wrong way.

Comment: palledue I corrected the integer value that was passed incorrectly. it is now fine. once again, thanks @swatsonpicken. fantastic day!

Comment: @Coder_Techie Happy to help. I edited my answer to make the function more explicit and to return a string (OK or Not OK) rather than a boolean.

Answer (score 0):

Always more than one way of doing things. A simplified version of the above code example that returns a boolean value could look like this

```
Function IsOk(firstValue As String, secondValue As String, thisValue As String) As Boolean
    If IsNumeric(firstValue) And IsNumeric(secondValue) And IsNumeric(thisValue) Then
        Dim x As Integer = firstValue
        Dim y As Integer = secondValue
        Dim z As Integer = thisValue
        If (z >= x And z <= y) Or (z >= y And z <= x) Then
            Return True
        End If
    End If
    Return False
End Function
```